# How to Import Exceptions from Package (Openpyxl)?

Tags: python, exception, openpyxl

I am trying to catch a sheet error exception for the package I am using (Openpyxl). I tried importing the exception like so `from openpyxl.utils import SheetTitleException` but I get the error `"ImportError: cannot import name SheetTitleException"`. When I tried importing it just with `from openpyxl.utils import *`, I get the error `NameError: global name 'SheetTitleException' is not defined`.

I'm sure I'm importing it incorrectly, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

[Here is the documentation on exceptions for Openpyxl.](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/_modules/openpyxl/utils/exceptions.html#SheetTitleException)

And here is the code I am using to catch the exception:

```
try:
    bdws = bdwb[finalBDSheetName]
except SheetTitleException:
    messageBox("Invalid sheet title. Check your sheet title and try again.")
    return
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to build an application around openpyxl. As the package author I would strongly advise against this.

Comment: @CharlieClark Could you explain why? Is it not designed for that?

Comment: No, it's designed around the file format, ie. data processing workflows. YMMV but we won't be adding Excel-like functionality.

Comment: Oh, I've been using it just to grab data from Excel sheets. Not necessarily try to modify them in an Excel-like manner. Also, since you're here, I've seen a lot of your posts around here and a few other places, just wanted to say thanks for working on Openpyxl and helping people out. The package works very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of the page you linked to says "openpyxl.utils.exceptions".

Therefore you should be doing:

```
from openpyxl.utils.exceptions import SheetTitleException
```

Comment: I think that gets me further, but now I get `KeyError: 'Worksheet notaworksheetname does not exist'`. Is the exception not being caught correctly?

Comment: @DouglasTrippe You are catching a `SheetTitleException` but the exception raised is `KeyError`...

Comment: I guess the SheetTitleException is for invalid sheet names, not missing ones then? That makes sense.
To add, is there a `KeyError` exception? Because I tried to catch it, but I got the same error. 
Edit: Putting KeyError first does work.

Comment: @DouglasTrippe What same error? Did you do `except KeyError`? This is what you should be catching.

Comment: Putting `KeyError` first does work. If I put it second though, I got the same error `KeyError: 'Worksheet notaworksheetname does not exist'`. But that was because I was missing parentheses.

Comment: May well drop `SheetTitleException` to be honest and just go with  `ValueError` but that won't help with the need to quote (if you have spaces or hyphens in the sheet name).

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like other module exception handling that i've done it should be

```
from openpyxl.utils.exceptions import SheetTitleException
```

then to use it

```
except SheetTitleException as e:
    # do something
```